# How to display category specific post content on a page

Tags: theme-development

Hi I need to display posts in a category on my page template. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: see this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3667/19691

Answer (score 1):

### Codex

Just take a look at the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

### Templates

You'll find out that WordPress has three different types of templates, that you can use:

A) For built in taxonomies: Category & Tag

B) For custom taxonomies.

The template engine will search for such templates when you request a category/tag/custom taxonomy archive page.

- `taxonomy-{$taxonomy_slug}-{$term}.php`

  - » `taxonomy-{$taxonomy_slug}.php`
  - » `taxonomy.php`
- `category-{$slug}.php`

  - » `category-{$id}.php`
  - » `category.php`
- `tag-{$slug}.php`

  - » `tag-{$id}.php`
  - » `tag.php`

### Overview

[image: Template Hierarchy by Chip Bennet]

<sup>The excellent diagramm by our man [Chip Bennet](http://www.chipbennett.net/themes/template-hierarchy/).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this to say you want to add a list of category posts on a page view, not a single post view. That being the case I would first suggest looking at one of what I imagine are numerous plugins that can provide this functionality.

An example plugin would be BNS Featured Category* which provides a shortcode that should accomplish what you are looking to do.

Link: [BNS Featured Category on WordPress Extend](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bns-featured-category)

*NB: Full disclosure, I wrote BNS Featured Category.

Answer (score 0):

Try using child theme. Create a custom template and try the following code.

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: template name
 */
?>
<?php get_header();
        $recent = new WP_Query("category_name="categoryname"&posts_per_page=5"); 
        while($recent->have_posts()):$recent->the_post();?>

        <?php the_content(); 

        endwhile;


 get_footer();
 ?>
```