# how to "not" display new posts with a specific category on the main page?

Tags: categories, blog

I've read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63085/how-to-display-category-specific-post-content-on-a-page) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77966/display-all-posts-from-specific-categories-on-a-page) but I'm just a basic user.

I have a "technical" blog that more and more people visit.

I'm a freelance, and now, when someone hears about me, he/she wants to search for me, and my blog is #1 (before anything else).

The problem is that it was a personal blog, and now it becomes professionnal. So I would still like to post some articles, but when there are some specific tags (like "games", "family" and so on), I'd like them **not** to appear on the main page but only under the category filter (`http://myblog/?s=game`, `http://myblog/?s=family` would be ok, but *not* `http://myblog/`).

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is even an example in the WordPress codex here for this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-3,-8' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Just modify the category IDs (replace -3,-8 by your category IDs preceded by the minus sign) and put it in your functions.php or your plugin code.

The WordPress codex states the following:

> `query_posts()` is the easiest, but not preferred or most efficient, way to alter the default query. The preferred way is hooking into `pre_get_posts` and altering the main query.

This way you just alter the main query instead of throwing away the results of the first query and running a second.

Comment: Ok, but where should I put this code?

Comment: functions.php, a plugin, etc

Comment: +1 for using `pre_get_posts`

Answer (score 0):

This is basic `The Loop` manipulation. You can edit your Loop to exclude specified categories. You would, for instance, use this modified Loop only in `index.php`, so on the front page it would exclude those categories, but they'd show on all other template pages.

For more information on using `The Loop` to exclude categories, check out [this WordPress Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category).

Basically

```
query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-3,-8');
```

Where `-3` means "exclude category with `ID 3`".

To figure out the ID of a category, navigate to your list of categories in WP-Admin, hover your mouse over a category title and in the URL it leads to is a parameter `ID`.

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend against the user of `query_posts`

Comment: To clarify, always use WP_Query or the pre_get_posts filter instead, query_posts will wastefully discard the main query, and overwrite it with a second new query

Comment: Isn't it difficult to use `pre_get_posts` and make this work **only** for the front page? More specifically, I am referring to [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#A_Warning_About_Conditional_Functions). Also, using a new WP_Query will indeed not stomp on the original query, but that is not going to be used anyways (so it's still wasted). Your comment has added value, still. Thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't want to use template functions inside pre_get_posts, it's for modifying the query variables, and only modifying the query variables ( which is what you're doing in query_posts, although in a wasteful roundabout way ). pre_get_posts isn't complicated, and the majority of it is copy paste

Comment: Refer to the answer from @Dehalion for an example

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand the differences and why there is so much critique on `query_posts()`. Specially after reading [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a template you can use the following code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Template name
  */
?>
<?php 
    get_header();
    $recent = new WP_Query("cat=-6");// Excludes the category with id=6  
    while($recent->have_posts()):$recent->the_post();
    the_title() 
    the_content();  
    endwhile;
    get_footer();
?>
```

See [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for more info.

Comment: I've edited your answer, WP_Query can't be used like a function, perhaps you can ellaborate? Also this is essentially a better written version of query_posts, and is still wasting an entire DB query, which is why pre_get_posts is recommended

Comment: I have edited the answer...!!!!!